# IntelliJ include external JARS in JavaFX JAR file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

How can I include all the jar files under lib in my main jar file produced ?

Is IntelliJ meant to create JAR files or not ? Cause I can't seem to make it work. Here are some screens from my setup:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

Could somebody explain to me why the other JAR file is generated outside my main JAR file?

AM I supposed to ship 2 JARS?

Comment: No you are not, I fought with this once, give me a moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go like this for one jar:

Right click > Open Module Settings > Artifacts > + > JAR > From module with dependencies

Then choose main class and select **EXTRACT TO TARGET JAR**, then press ok. And close all dialogs applying and ok'ing.

When done coding, goto Build > Build Artifacts > ...jar > Build.

The jar should be there. Make sure to vipe your /out before.

Comment: Seriously Intellij?? Why ? Why do they make it so hard to do ? How I am supposed to do that with no documentation? Anyway thanks it works now. btw do you know how to change an icon for a jar file?

Comment: Have never sone it but can give a look 2morrow

Comment: Consider this Trt Trt http://www.coderanch.com/t/513237/java/java/change-icon-jar-file Sorry no better help :S

Comment: you are a life savior, I was insisting on moving the library under my jar, I didn't even think about creating a new archive like a JAR and not a javafx application from the top left +

Comment: What is the point of exporting as a JavaFX application if exporting directly as a jar works [event better]?