# How do I export a JavaFX Application and dependencies in the same jar in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to export my JavaFX application that uses the jsoup library as a single jar. In File > Project Structure, I am able to drag jsoup into my jar, but this creates two jar files when I build the artifact, and removing the jsoup jar causes my program not to work. I just want one jar that I can distribute, so what am I doing wrong? I've posted my artifact configuration below.

[image: First Tab]

[image: Second Tab]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611848/intellij-include-external-jars-in-javafx-jar-file). You need to in the Output Layout tab, you need to *leave* the library in the "Available Elements" section, right-click it, and select "Extract Into Output Root". This will cause "Extracted 'library name'" to appear on in the Output Directory section, and you can just drag it into the main jar. I wish it was more obvious! Please leave a comment if anyone is having trouble with this.